# Firebase orderByChild in android; can't get it to work

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have data structure as:

```
https://law-apps-44h221543638e.firebaseio.com/apps to promote/0/ >> name:"First App", package:"fra"
https://law-apps-44h221543638e.firebaseio.com/apps to promote/1/ >> name:"Second App", package:"sca"
https://law-apps-44h221543638e.firebaseio.com/apps to promote/2/ >> name:"Third App", package:"tha"
```

and I query it using

```
Firebase myFirebaseReference = new Firebase("https://law-apps-44h221543638e.firebaseio.com/apps to promote");
Query queryRef = myFirebaseReference.orderByChild("name");

queryRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() { // override methods })
```

But it returns the data in the same order i.e sorted by the first child (1,2,3, etc.)
How should I query it so it sorts the data by the "name" tag of each child?

Comment: Most likely you have a mistake in the `ValueEventListener` implementation. Note that we just added an extra sample to the documentation to show how to loop over the children in your `ValueEventListener`: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data#filtering_data

Comment: Yes you were right! I was using an older technique wherein I was finding from datasnapshot my apps using their parents' numbers. Now I have used dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator() and it is now working correctly. Thanks for the hint! :)

Comment: Good to hear that you fixed it. Can you post an answer with the code if how you now loop over the children? It may be helpful to developers that run into this problem in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I found the answer to this question and I am writing it so others may benefit from it. I was using an older technique wherein I was finding from datasnapshot my apps using their parents' numbers and due to this, I was delibrately undoing the ordering.

Now I have used dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator() and it is now working correctly. Here's the code:

```
Query queryRef = myFirebaseReference.orderByChild("name");

    queryRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    String name;
    String my_package;

    long lengthOfForLoop = dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
    Iterator<DataSnapshot> child = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();
    for (int i = 0; i < lengthOfForLoop; i++) {
            DataSnapshot next = child.next();
            name = next.child("name").getValue(String.class);
            my_package = next.child("package").getValue(String.class);
              // do something with this data.
               }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks, Usman!

I used the same code with the children iterable collection in a for loop.
This code was worked for me (in Kotlin):

```
 accountsReference.child(accountId).child("actions").orderByChild("actionPosition").addListenerForSingleValueEvent( object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(var1: DataSnapshot) {
                if (var1.children != null) {
                    for (actionsEntries in var1.children) {
                       ...
                    }
                }
```